# Cannot log in to Facebook comments using Hotmail on IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, authentication, comments, hotmail, facebook-social-plugins

We are using the Facebook comments plugin on our site.   For the most part, it works fine in Firefox and Chrome.    We allow users to log in to comment using Facebook, Yahoo, AOL, or Hotmail.    When someone visits the site using IE and they click the "Comment using..." box, it works ok if they log in using Facebook.   But if they try to log in using Hotmail the following occurs:   The Hotmail login box pops up and the user enters his credentials and hits the connect button.   The box goes away and all seems fine, but on the source page, the "Comment using..." button is still present.   Normally, once you have logged in, it will show which service you are logged in as.

Some of the other login services also do not work in IE, and some do not work in Safari.   Does anyone know a way around this problem?

Comment: Log it at http://bugs.developers.facebook.net

Comment: It is but it hasn't been acted on http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=18891  Would it help to get people to vote?

Comment: This site is for programming questions not bugs or discussions.

Comment: @OffBySome: Sheesh... Harold's programming quesiton is "how can I write code that works around this bug?"

Answer (score 0):

go to settings in hotmail (in IE)

and use https automatic

ans it works